# Relationship between model and template - magento

Tags: magento-1.7

Somebody told template read content from `model` via `block`.

My question:

1.Have any possibility to read content `directly` from `model`?

2.If Is this possible,How can I achieve?

3.In which situation, `block` interact with `template` and `model`?

4.If I using only `template` and `model`, have any `drawback` in this?

Comment: Could you please rephrase all of that with complete sentences? As it is unclear what you're asking.

Comment: You also seem to be confused about models, blocks and such, I suggest you take a look at [Alan Storm's explanation on Magento's MVC](http://alanstorm.com/2009/img/magento-book/magento-mvc.png)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get Model any where in magento, by this code

```
Mage::getModel('module/module')->getCollection();
```

> If you get model in view(template) file then site loading time will increase.

So the standard way in **MVC** is create collection in model, get it from block and call it in template file.

Cheers

Comment: ok. Have any possible reason for increasing execution time?

Comment: @user6085 increasing execution means, you need to speed up the site?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. My question is  Have any possible reason for decreasing execution time when we directly use model?

Comment: If you use directly, you can't speed up the site. So follow the MVC Pattern to increase to speed up the site.